# Factorial Divisibility

Tags: divisibility, factorial

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers greater than one.
With that in mind, $$(a \cdot b)!$$ is not necessarily divisible by:

a) $$a!^b$$
b) $$b!^a$$
c) $$a! \cdot b!$$
d) $${2}^{ab}$$

By brute-forcing, I found that letter D is the answer, can someone solve this in a non-brute-force way?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual solution,  but: if it was known that the question only had a single correct answer, you could rule out a) and b) because by symmetry, either they are both true or both false.

Comment: @SteamyRoot: You typed faster than I did, so I won't duplicate your comment. But that's exactly what I was thinking. +1.

Comment: Taking $a=b=2$ provides a simple counterexample for (D), right? Is that what you mean by "brute-forcing"?

Comment: Yes, it is @MPW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option D looks suspicious..

The power of 2 in a factorial $((ab)!) $ is given by:

$$\left|\frac {ab}{2^1}\right|+\left|\frac {ab}{2^2}\right|+\left|\frac {ab}{2^3}\right| + \dots $$

This is definitely lesser than:

$$ab \left(\frac {1}{2^1}+\frac {1}{2^2}+\frac {1}{2^3} + \dots \right) $$

which is equal to $ab $. Hence $ab $ can never be the power of 2 in $(ab)! $

Comment: \left( \right) adjust parenthesis in all cases at the best size ;)

Comment: @Shadock can you please edit my answer as an example?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I added \left and \right, added \dots instead of "..", and used \$\$ for displaying instead of \$ for inline.

Comment: @DylanSP thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint $1:$**

For the first two, observe that the product of $n$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $n!$

**Hint $2:$**

$\frac{(a \cdot b)!}{a! \cdot b!}$ is a multiple of $\binom{a+b}{a}=\binom{a+b}{b}$, both of which clearly are natural numbers, as $ab \geq {a+b}$, for all $a,b \geq 2$

**Hint $3:$**

$a=b=2$ acts as a simple contradiction as pointed in comments by @MPW.

Comment: Your Hint 2 has a minor error: The fraction in question is not generally equal to those binomial coefficients, though it is a multiple of them, since $ab \geq a+b$ (for $a, b > 1$). ¶ For that matter, (A) is equal to $\binom{ab}{a, a, \ldots, a}$ and (B) is equal to $\binom{ab}{b, b, \ldots, b}$ and both of those are natural numbers, too.